# Find all tasks that contain subtasks inside

Tags: jira, jql

It doesn't matter what values the fields have. I am interested in the fact of the existence of a subtask inside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the following JQL:

```
issueFunction in hasSubtasks()
```

it filters for such issues which satisfy condition hasSubtasks() which is a function for identifying issues with subtasks (but not other types of links).

Comment: Why? Can you [edit] your answer to explain what this does and why it solves this problem? Offering a suggestion is welcome, but backing it up with an explanation will make your answer more useful for future readers.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are no special operators in JQL for such cases but I've found the solution:

using obviously non-existent task names in combination with **issueFunction in parentsOf()**

like this **issueFunction in parentsOf("issue != BLABLA-100")**

It works! And if you wanna get issues without subtasks you can put **NOT** before the request described above